# Returning factors when applying a function to transform a dataframe of integers to decimal

Tags: r

I am trying to transform a column of integers to decimal:

CI

```
14   15  16
17   18  19
20   21  22
```

```
CI_decimal<-as.data.frame(apply(CI, 2, function(x) format(x, nsmall=3)))
```

When applying this, I obtain:

```
14.000  15.000  16.000
17.000  18.000  19.000
20.000  21.000  22.000
```

The problem is that now this values have been transformed to factors.

If I transform each column to numeric again `as.numeric()`, then I obtain again integers, not decimals.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `apply`, we can use `lapply` and assign it back to the original dataset

```
CI[] <- lapply(CI, format, nsmall = 2)
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
CI_NEW <- CI %>%
               mutate_all(format, nsmall = 2)
```

---

The issue is that the `apply` returns `character` output and `as.data.frame` by default use `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` for non-numeric elements.  It can be corrected with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the original code

```
as.data.frame(apply(CI, 2, function(x) 
       format(x, nsmall=3)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```